# error: conversion from 'void' to non-scalar type 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits requested

Tags: c++

full error message:

```
error: conversion from 'void' to non-scalar type 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >' requested
```

```
  1 #include <iostream>
  2 #include <iomanip>
  3 #include <fstream>
  4 #include <vector>
  5 using namespace std;
  6
  7 token parseLine(string s, char i);
 53 int main()
 54 {
 55    string line;
 56    char delim = '|';
 57    ifstream inputStream("test.txt");
 58
 59    while( getline(inputStream, line) )
 60    {
 61       vector<string> tokens = parseLine( line, delim);
 62       if(tokens[0][0] != '#')
 63       {
 64          cout << tokens[0];
 65          cout << tokens[1];
 66          cout << tokens[2];
 67       }
 68    }
 69 }
```

Please excuse the 8-52 line skip, that's commented out "stuff that didn't work".

I'm not sure how to declare `parseLine`, nothing I try works: `void`, `int`, `double`, `string`, etc;

Any pointers on how to declare `parseLine` so that it does what I want?

Comment: You probably want `std::vector<std::string> parseLine(string s, char i);`, since that's what you're assigning the result to.

Comment: What does `parseLine` return? And how is the object it returns declared inside the function?

Comment: Line 61 gives your lots of information...

Comment: @billz That information may as well be wrong.

Comment: I'm honestly just doing what another user here posted on a different question. After sorting through most of the errors of the things he posted, I came up with this error. He wrote parseLine as if it is a function in the C Libraries, which I have found to be false. So, I'm not really sure. If I don't put anything up at the top (the parseLine(string s, char i)) then it spits out parseLine not declared.

Comment: What is `token` and where is it declared?

Comment: It really isn't as far as I know. I appologize, the error message is from having "void parseLine(string s, char i);".

Comment: It is very simple. You have a function returning something incompatible or nothing, and it is being used to assign to an `std::vector<std::string>`. This is what the compiler and Olaf's answer are telling you.

Comment: vector<string> parseLine(string s, char i); throws:
(.text+0xc6): undefined reference to `parseLine(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, char)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

vector<token> parseLine(string s, char i); throws:
hw8.cpp:7: error: âtokenâ was not declared in this scope
hw8.cpp:7: error: template argument 1 is invalid
hw8.cpp:7: error: template argument 2 is invalid
hw8.cpp:7: error: invalid type in declaration before â;â token
hw8.cpp: In function âint main()â:
hw8.cpp:61: error: conversion from âintâ to non-scalar type â>...requested

Comment: You need to provide an implementation (known as a "definition") for the function in question. It looks like your compiler cannot find one. It is also complaining about "token".

Answer (score 1):

`parseLine()` must return a `vector<string>`:

```
vector<string> parseLine(string s, char i);
```

if it should fit to line 61. But since you return a `token` it might also be

```
vector<token> parseLine(string s, char i);
```

what you intended.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is read in input in the form of C1|c3|c4 and then separating it based on the |. So, I don't even really know what all that code is doing; I just know that it was posted in an intent to solve the problem I presented. After sorting through the errors of the code, I am left with parseLine not declared if I put nothing up there.

Comment: Then you should ask the person, who posted the code. We can just guess, what it should do based on the name. When you remove the `parseLine()` declaration, the compiler of course complains about it, because it must the know the declaration in order to compile it properly. From the comments above, you must also implement the `parseLine()` function, which means, define what the function should do to split the line at the "|".